# Calculate 64bit jmp for code cave in c#

Tags: c#, codecave

i cannot solve my problem. Any help appreciated.
I want to create a jmp to my allocated memory. 
If i check my calculation with cheat engine allocated memory it is fine. 
Cause Cheat Engine allocates memory in a higher region. 
My allocated memory is e.g: 0x870000 and the adress where i want to create the jmp is at: 7FFDE65F5184.

```
Console.WriteLine("toWrite: {0:x}", toWrite.ToInt64()); /*toWrite: 7FFDE65F5184*/
IntPtr allocation = VirtualAllocEx(openproc, IntPtr.Zero , 0x1024, AllocationType.Commit | AllocationType.Reserve, MemoryProtection.ExecuteReadWrite);

Console.WriteLine("allocation: {0:x}", allocation.ToInt64()); /* allocation: 870000*/

IntPtr jmp = new IntPtr((toWrite.ToInt64() - (allocation.ToInt64() + 5)));

byte[] bytes1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(jmp.ToInt64());


byte[] bytes2 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, };
bytes2[0] = 233;
bytes2[1] = bytes1[0];
bytes2[2] = bytes1[1];
bytes2[3] = bytes1[2];
bytes2[4] = bytes1[3];
/*nops*/
bytes2[5] = 144;
bytes2[6] = 144;
bytes2[7] = 144;
bytes2[8] = 144;
UIntPtr written = new UIntPtr();
WriteProcessMemory(openproc, toWrite, bytes2, 9, out written);
```

50% of the result is correct. anyone can help?

This is my result:

```
7FFDE65F5184 - E9 77AE271A           - jmp 7FFE00870000
```

Why is there 7FFE00 in front of my needed jmp adress ?
if i choose another value than IntPtr.Zero in VirtualAllocEx the return value is 0 - dont know why! i know it is not well coded, but first of all i want to understand what is my problem and how i can solve this issue.

Thanks so much guys!

Comment: Isn't JMP (E9, 233), limited to 32 bits jumps? You can't jump the distance you need.

Comment: By using the second parameter of `VirtualAllocEx` you can ask for the allocation of memory in a particular "place"... But you have to do it by trial (begin with the given address rounded to for example 16mb and then begin adding 16mb searching for a "free" memory page until you are able to allocate your block)

Comment: Your code location is high. Aside from asking for an absolute address (which is potentially tricky, as xanatos has pointed out), you can also try passing `MEM_TOP_DOWN` to get an allocation that's as high as possible. Alternatively, you could generate code for an absolute jump, but if you're patching existing bytes that may not be an option. Even so, [there's multiple ways](http://www.ragestorm.net/blogs/?p=1070).

Answer (score 0):

Wow guys! You ve inspired me and i got my solution ... MEM_TOP_DOWN did the job! Thanks so much!